# how to fix this memory leaking function in raylib c++?

Tags: c++, raylib

I'm learning C++ and I'm using raylib to make maps using perlin noise, just for fun. I'm generating a lot of things but for goods I want a diferent map for each good that shows the provinces where that good is available. I did that but I'm realizing that it using a lot of RAM. I used -fasanitzer and it says that is in this function, but I cannot see a solution. I already delete the img.data but if I try to delete the byte array "pixels" it says double free.

I'm starting to learn smart pointers but would like know what's wrong.

Thanks in advance :)

I will leave the github repository also just in case. [repository](https://github.com/digaso/sim)

```
void renderGoodMap(World* w, Texture2D* tex) {
  vector<Good> g = w->getGoods();
  int cols = w->get_num_cols();
  int rows = w->get_num_rows();

  for (uint i = 0; i < g.size(); i++) {
    byte* pixels = new byte[ rows * cols * 4 ];
    bool* map = w->getGoodMapById(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < rows * cols; j++) {
      int index = j * 4;
      if (map[ j ]) {
        pixels[ index + 0 ] = (byte)255;
        pixels[ index + 1 ] = (byte)0;
        pixels[ index + 2 ] = (byte)0;
        pixels[ index + 3 ] = (byte)150;
      }
      else {
        pixels[ index + 0 ] = (byte)255;
        pixels[ index + 1 ] = (byte)255;
        pixels[ index + 2 ] = (byte)255;
        pixels[ index + 3 ] = (byte)100;
      }
    }
    Image img = {
      .data = pixels,
      .width = cols,
      .height = rows,
      .mipmaps = 1,
      .format = 7
    };
    ImageResizeNN(&img, cols * TILESIZE, rows * TILESIZE);
    tex[ i ] = LoadTextureFromImage(img);
    delete img.data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Side note: Don't shoot yourself in the foot with crap like this if you don't have to. Start with a `std::vector` and see if that's performant enough.

Comment: This is unnecessary. Either use a cheap `std::unique_ptr<byte[]>` or a `std::vector<byte>`. Also you can easily check how many bytes your program doesn't free by using *Valgrind*. It can be helpful.

Comment: `delete img.data;` -> `delete[] img.data;`. The first says delete one `byte`. The second says delete an array of `byte`. Using the wrong one can cause interesting problems.

Comment: If you're learning C++ the first thing to *unlearn* is making manual allocations using `new`. Learn to leverage containers like `std::vector`. Remember, [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) rules complicate even the most trivial allocation strategy.

Comment: thank you all for responding, but when I try vector it gives me this error
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
[1]    16802 IOT instruction (core dumped)

i am using the vector how you said and giving picels.data() to the image object
and I removed the delete[]

[link](https://cl1p.net/uqzgepakquhtc ) here a clipboard of what I changed

Comment: Then possibly your error is somewhere else (where you possibly corrupted the memory) and not `std::vector`.